# C undefined symbol at runtime

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

I have inherited a codebase that I am attempting to build and run.  I have been able to do so before, but now on a different system I am getting some runtime errors, even though compilation goes fine.  I am quite new to C and would appreciate any suggestions to move forward.

Specifically, I have a directory, `common`, of common utilities, which gets built into a shared library, and when the main program tries to use symbols from the shared library, I get errors like this:

```
some_file.so: undefined symbol: CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL
```

The symbol is declared within a header file, `custom_log.h`, like so:

```
extern int CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL;
```

The symbol is defined within the `custom_log.c` file, like so:

```
int CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL = DEFAULT_CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL;
```

These logger files are contained in a directory of other common utilities, which are all brought together in a file `common.h`.  Here is how the logger is included in the common library:

```
#include "custom_log.h"
```

After I have run configure, make, and make install, the relevant contents of the lib directory look like this:

```
libsomething_common.so -> libsomething_common.so.0.0.0
libsomething_common.so.0 -> libsomething_common.so.0.0.0
libsomething_common.so.0.0.0
```

So there are a few symlinked .so files, and the one they end up pointing to is `libsomething_common.so.0.0.0`.  Analyzing the file with the `objdump` command yields the following results:

```
$ objdump -t libsomething_common.so.0.0.0 | grep CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL
0000000000209a20 l     O .data  0000000000000004              CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL
```

```
$ objdump -T libsomething_common.so.0.0.0 | grep CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL
```

So we can see that the symbol is not dynamic, and I believe it should be.  But how to make that happen?

Again, I am very new to this build process and appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: Are you specifying the `something_common` library in your linker arguments?

Comment: Perhaps you're compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`. I'd try slapping a visibility attribute on the symbol: `int CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL __attribute__((visibility("default"))) = DEFAULT_CUSTOM_LOG_LEVEL;`

Comment: @PSkocik is right, also keep an eye over `#pragma GCC visibility push(<<val>>)` too if it's GCC

Comment: You can to tell the linker where the runtime library path is `-Wl-,rpath`, or set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` prior to execution, or on Linux, add a config in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` followed with `ldconfig`.

Comment: Yes @PSkocik you got it, thank you.  I was indeed compiling with `fvisibility=hidden`.  Setting the visibility attribute on the symbol fixes the runtime error. The library path was being passed to the linker, so that was not the problem. And thank you @user7859067 for informing me of another mechanism of setting visibility.